# How to make grunt to output different names [random string].main.js when building?

Tags: build, gruntjs

Two months ago the grunt build worked well by outputting a [random string].main.js (and css). Also would replace the js and css blocks with the useminPrepare, usemin... But now I don't know why but the build is just a main.js file. The settings are the same, I've also tried to go at a version where I'm sure that the gruntconfig file outputted a correct build, but no luck. It seems that something changed and messed up my config, here it go my config: https://gist.github.com/totty90/8584989

What happened? thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like a problem with [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev), have you updated some node modules?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure which ones...

Comment: Try running with a `-v` flag, that could give us some more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very strange. I've seen from running `grunt build --verbose` that was not running some tasks. The grunt task is:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'copy-extra-css',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    // 'uglify',
    'modernizr', <-- Grunt was stopping at this (but would still run modernizer)
    'copy:dist',
    'devcode:dist',
    'rev:dist',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Very strange right? Then I've removed the task, maybe is overriding something, but no, grunt was not working anymore.

Then I've **changed the grunt task name to build2 and now it works!!**

```
grunt.registerTask('build2', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'copy-extra-css',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'requirejs',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    // 'uglify',
    'modernizr',
    'copy:dist',
    'devcode:dist',
    'rev:dist',
    'usemin'
]);
```

In the current yeoman version this is not a problem anymore.